# Ways to store Custom Object(not implementing NSCoding) in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I want to store some Custom Objects in NSUserDefaults. I know that, it should be implementing the NSCoding Protocol. But the issue is that, I can't change that Class as it is provided by some SDK.

So are there any ways to store these Custom Objects?

Comment: How about using a wrapper class and making it implement `NSCoding`?

Comment: What about the other functions which are expecting class of that type? I can't change the SDK behaviour.

Comment: You don't need to. See my edits below.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own custom class which contains all the fields of the original class.  Then you get most (if not all) of your encoding for free.
The end result is very similar to implementing NSCoding for the original object, since all changes are restricted to an "encode" and a "decode" (save/restore) function. Nothing else in your project has to change.

**Edit**:

You could create two special archive functions

```
func saveToArchive(customObject: CustomObject) -> Bool {  
    <your code; return true if succeeded> 
}

func loadFromArchive(identifier: Int) -> CustomObject? {
  let newObject = CustomObject
 < again your code to retrieve the correct object (your version);
   assign each field to newObject and return it, return nil you have an issue>
}
```

By following this approach, you basically never use your version of the object, except in transitioning to/from persisted store (database, archive, etc.)  Similar to the "Adapter" Software Design Pattern (or wrapper).

Comment: What about the other functions which are expecting class of that type? I can't change the SDK behaviour.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide one possible solution. You create your object using the CustomObject data, save it, retrieve it and convert it back to the CustomObject again as needed. Your version of the object doesn't exist outside the archival functions, so it doesn't affect the rest of the code in your project.